# xcode,ios8, swift, files and arrays

Tags: arrays, xcode, file, swift

I am trying to add persistance to my application, so i have to read and write to a file

This is the code i use to read:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: "txt")
var text = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
```

and this is the line I use to write

```
text.writeToFile(path!, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Here happens something strange,there is no Data.txt file in my project folder but it works.Why?

To solve this i deleted some folders,created a Data.txt file in the project folder and the app work fine but i cannot see the data stored in the txt file,why?And if i delete the file the app doesn't show errors and continues to work even if i moved to thrash the file.How is it possible?How can I edit or delete this file before it's loaded in the application?

Another issue I have is that i would like to use an array instead of a big string,the array should be like this

```
var array = [(number:Int(),name:String(),date:String())]
```

the txt file has the following structure
number\tname\tdate\nnumber\tname\tdate and so on

I don't know how to split the different lines of the file into an array and the 3 elements of the line into an element of the array using "\n" as separator for the elements and \t to separate the Int and the two Strings

And I don't know how to save the array in the txt file and reload it,do I have to use some for cycle or some while or there is some function specific for my case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to save a tuple using NSUserDefaults, so I think you should use a subarray to group your data before storing it:

```
class Load {
    class func array(key:String) -> [AnyObject]! {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey(key)
    }
}
class Save {
    class func array(key:String, _ value:[AnyObject]){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value, forKey: key)
    }

}
var number = 15
var name = "John"
var date = NSDate()

var myArray:[[AnyObject]] = []

myArray.append([number,name,date])

Save.array("myArray", myArray)

number = 16
name = "Jane"
date = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24)

myArray.append([number,name,date])
Save.array("myArray", myArray)


let loadedArray = Load.array("myArray")
```